# Error on using PROC IOMOPERATE Custom Task

Tags: sas, procedure

I am trying to use the Custom Task to list and stop the active SAS sessions. I downloaded the dll files from

https://communities.sas.com/t5/Administration-and-Deployment/A-custom-task-to-list-and-stop-active-SAS-sessions/m-p/251340

and then I created a folder named "Custom" in C:\Program Files\SAS\EnterpriseGuide\4.3 and pasted the dll file in this folder.

But when I tried to run the Custom Task from SAS EG, it showed the error saying "**Error: Procedure IOMOPERATE not found**".

I, also, tried to run the procedure using following code with my credentials

```
%let connection=
'iom://myserver.company.com:8581;bridge;user=sasadm@saspw,pass=Secret01';

/* Get a list of processes */
proc iomoperate uri=&connection.;
list spawned out=spawned;
quit;
```

found this code on http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2016/02/15/using-proc-iomoperate/

I am not able to figure out where am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you post on communities the author of the tasks can chime in.

Comment: Could you post results you get in log from running `proc setinit; run;` ?